# Swiping between action bar tabs on android version lower than 3.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe, swipe-gesture

First of all I got my support libraries and all and I absolutely don't want to use sherlock or some support library like that.

Here's my activity code:

```
    public class MyClass ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_class);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
}
static ActionBar actionBar;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    //       Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater upInflater = getMenuInflater();
    upInflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
    // setup action bar for tabs
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_home)
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment1>(
                    this, home, Fragment1.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_cart)
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment2>(
                    this, cart, Fragment2.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_users)
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment3>(
                    this, users, Fragment3.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_products)
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment4>(
                    this, products, Fragment4.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_settings)
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment5>(
                    this, settings, Fragment5.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

As you can see I use fragments to travel between tabs also here is my TabListener:

```
     public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
      * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
      * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
      * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
      */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        actionBar.setTitle(mTag);// <===
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

This works perfectly alone. I have my layouts and classes for every fragment ready too. But I just can't seem to find a proper source for `ViewPager` for such style of code. Am I going in the wrong direction? What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what doesn't work?

Comment: @Szymon It works, I am asking how to add swipe ability to my action bar tabs.

Comment: Ok, got it. You should use the ViewPager for that, at least it works well for me.

Comment: @Szymon I wanted to but I don't know how to, I am a bit of a beginner, do you have an example for versions below 3.0?

Comment: Can't help you at the moment, don't have access to my code. If no one else answers, I'll do that tomorrow.

Comment: "First of all I got my support libraries and all and I absolutely don't want to use sherlock or some support library like that" -- then you cannot have "action bar tabs on android version lower than 3.0", because Android itself did not add an action bar until Android 3.0, and all backports of the action bar come in "some support library like that". "But I just can't seem to find a proper source for ViewPager for such style of code" -- you cannot have a `ViewPager`, because that is part of the Android Support project, and you decided not to use "some support library like that".

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi, thank you for your answer, I don't know why you have the attitude but well, with android's own support libraries I am able to add action bars for below 3.0, one can also use viewpager with it but I don't know how. I said I don't want to use a library like Sherlock but I of course would use android-support-v7-appcompat.

Comment: You can probably port http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html to the AppCompat action bar.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you! that gave me an idea actually. I created a test project in eclipse for higher than api level 11. And transformed the code suitable to the support library v7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by eclipses help. I created a project with swipe ability which works for api level HIGHER than 11. I edited the whole code and made it work by the help of support libraries appcompat 7 and 4. It's pretty easy and works pretty well.